# Image is stretched when place into carousal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, carousel

I am using a carousel where I put 5 images with different height and width but there are some issues with images, some images are stretched some images are the center of the carousel.

I want that all images fit inside the carousel.

Here is my code :

```
  <div uib-carousel active="active" class="filter-carousel" interval="false" no-wrap="noWrapSlides" ng-if="vm.temp.length">
  <div uib-slide ng-repeat="img in vm.temp" index="$index">
      <img ng-src="{{img.src}}" height="650">
  </div>
```

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: @Sumit please post your code what you have tried yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "**background-image**" attribute of the **div** tag. And set the "**background-size**" attribute to **contain** or **cover**. Eg :

```css
.owl-carousel .item img
{
    display: none;
}

.owl-carousel .item img + div
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 210px; /* option */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center; /* 0 0 */
    background-size: contain; /* or cover */
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
 <div class="item">
  <img src="http://example.com/" alt="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('http://example.com/')"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <img src="http://example.com/" alt="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('http://example.com/')"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <img src="http://example.com/" alt="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('http://example.com/')"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <img src="http://example.com/" alt="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('http://example.com/')"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <img src="http://example.com/" alt="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('http://example.com/')"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <img src="http://example.com/" alt="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('http://example.com/')"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used cover, but it will cut my images at some portion

Comment: As @clone : "You can use fill, contain, cover, none or scale down.". In my example, you can accept : "contain" or "cover". Otherwise, you might resize image before publishing!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [object-fit property in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) to define how an image should fit into a container. You can use fill, contain, cover, none or scale down.

```
.the-carousel img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: I used it but it is going to cut my images in some portion

Comment: How do I fix that

Comment: Since we don't know your HTML or CSS we can't help you with this. Please post a minimal working example where we can verify your problem.